# Slice of an array of slices of arrays

Tags: arrays, rust

I have an 2D array, and I want a function to change it. I don't know vectors yet, but since the array is going to have a fixed size, I don't need them. I wanted to give the function a slice of an array of slices of arrays, e. g. `fn my_func (arr: &mut [&mut [char]]) {...}`, but I don't know how to call it from my int main.

Here's an example I've been playing with.

```
fn main() {
    let mut map = [['-'; 3]; 3];

    for row in map {
        for col in row {
            print!("{} ", col);
        }

        println!("");
    }

    println!("Changing...");
    put_plus(???);

    for row in map {
        for col in row {
            print!("{} ", col);
        }

        println!("");
    }
}

fn put_plus(map: &mut [&mut [char]]) {
    map[map.len() - 1][map[map.len() - 1].len() - 2] = '+';
}
```

The output I expect is:

```
- - - 
- - - 
- - - 
Changing...
- - -
- - -
- + -
```

Is there an expression to turn `[[char; 3]; 3]` into `[[char]]` so that I could put this expression instead of `???` and everything works??

Comment: Your function should take a `&mut [[char; 3]; 3]`, and you can just pass `&mut map` to it. You don't need the inner `&mut` (it would mean you have an array of *references* to arrays, which you don't). And, you can't really make it work with slices because they are unsized, so you have to write out the lengths (you could use vectors if you wanted arbitrary lengths -- they are not complicated).

Comment: OP, this works indeed just as @FZs says https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=479719bc7ea9f95dd450a39b8878ac31

Comment: I did want not an example of a program but an expression that I can put instead of `???`. I just wondered if there's a simple expression that transforms `mut [[char; 3]; 3]` into `mut [[char]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version of the plus function that works for all sizes:

```rust
fn put_plus<const COUNT: usize>(map: &mut [[char; COUNT]; COUNT]) {
    map[map.len() - 1][map[map.len() - 1].len() - 2] = '+';
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, you just need a mutable reference on the "outer" struct. In Rust, you don't control mutability at the "element" level. Instead, mutability of a container extends to all the elements within that container. You can't have, for example, a mutable vector containing immutable vectors or a mutable array containing immutable arrays.

So, just slapping a `&mut` to the "outside" of your array means everything in your array, including the inner arrays AND the values contained within those inner arrays, will be mutable.

EDIT: My version of `put_plus` will only work for square arrays. As commenter @cafce25 points out, the outer `:COUNT` can be removed. That will make it more general

Comment: Thanks, now this is much clearer, now I see why there's no simple expression to what I wanted.

Comment: Nit: You can and should remove the outer `;COUNT` as it's unnecessary and makes the function less general.